# How to reinstall grub by ubuntu 14.04 live CD?

Tags: grub2

How to reinstall grub by ubuntu 14.04 live CD?
Could you show me the installed steps?

Thanks.

Regards,
David

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System

Answer (score 1):

This should let you install GRUB onto your computer.

1. Boot from the LiveCD and select the "Try Ubuntu" option.
2. Once booted, open a terminal, either by searching for it or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.
3. From the terminal, run

   ```
   sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
   ```

   - Note: **X** is the letter assigned to your hard drive. To find this, follow the steps below.
4. Search for Gparted in the Live Environment, open it and let it scan.
5. Once it's finished scanning, look at the top right corner of the Gparted window.
6. There should be a drive name here, most likely `/dev/sda`. It might be `sdb` or `sdc`, though.
7. Whatever the letter happens to be, use that in place of **X** in the command above.

If you have any questions, just ask.