# What's the Easiest Way to Clone Boot Partition?

Tags: ssd, clone, clonezilla

Right now I'm using a 1TB HDD for Ubuntu 18.10, but the used space is only 50GB (single partition). I'm looking to buy a 250GB SSD and install 18.10 there but I don't want to do clean install because it will take time to set everything the way I want again.

Now I'm in the middle of shrinking the 1TB partition to 100GB, because like I read on Internet, we can't clone partition that's bigger than the destination drive/partition. So, what's the easiest way to do that? I've read about Clonezilla but there's only tutorial for drive-to-drive cloning, not partition-to-partition.

Please help me, thanks :)

Comment: Is this what you want? https://askubuntu.com/questions/842029/cloning-hard-disk-partition-to-smaller-ssd-on-laptop

Comment: @cliffflip that being said I found that clonezilla on the first ever time I used it to be incredibly intuitive. I didn't really need a guide. clonezilla is really easy if you just want an exact duplicate of a drive onto another drive. if you want just part of a drive I imagine it can be used as well but you'll have a couple more tuning actions to perform before hitting "start" that being.

Comment: Thanks for your replies man. Between gparted and clonezilla, which one you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

honestly for what you want to do clonezilla is the way to go. it works like an Ubuntu Live CD/USB, you just burn it to your usb and then you boot to it. instead of a desktop you're greeted with (in my experience) an intuitive and straightforward UI that guides you throuh the cloning process.

(yes, in my case I was actually cloning a 120GB drive to a 1TB, it created everything on the 1TB drive as if it was 120GB so only 120GB were formatted and occupied but that's fine, afterwards I booted to this terabyte drive and used Paragon (it was a windows) (I think on windows 10 you can also use windows's built in partition manager) to resize the main partition so that the whole 1TB was occupied entirely, real easy)

be sure to have the drive you want to clone and the drive you want to clone to plugged in before you boot to clonezilla!