# I think the boot time of my laptop is slow for ssd

Tags: boot, 18.04, ssd

I just upgraded my HDD to SSD to improve the performance of my system. I followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842029/cloning-hard-disk-partition-to-smaller-ssd-on-laptop) and it's working well.

But, I think that the boot time is just the same as before. I also searched about it and found some resources to try.

So i reinstalled the NVIDIA drivers, but nothing changed. I also tried to fix the resume thing but I couldn't find the `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` file.

Here is the output of `systemd-analyze time`:

```
Startup finished in 3.982s (firmware) + 10.968s (loader) + 2.105s kernel) + 11.454s (userspace) = 28.510s 
graphical.target reached after 9.380s in userspace
```

`lsblk` output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0   5.8M  1 loop /snap/htop/1168
loop1    7:1    0 149.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/67
loop2    7:2    0 136.7M  1 loop /snap/code/15
loop3    7:3    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100
loop4    7:4    0     4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/406
loop5    7:5    0  42.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
loop6    7:6    0  88.5M  1 loop /snap/core/7270
loop7    7:7    0  54.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/1066
loop8    7:8    0  14.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/296
loop9    7:9    0  1008K  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/61
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0 465.3G  0 part /
```

`cat /etc/fstab` output:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=6ca24650-d418-47c8-8a9b-33c115766285 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=461C-0619  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=461C-0619  /boot/efi   vfat    defaults    0   1
```

If you guys need more info please let me know and thank you in advance.

**EDITED**

Here is the output of `systemd-analyzed blame` :

```
6.175s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          5.039s bolt.service
          4.451s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          1.289s apparmor.service
          1.219s plymouth-read-write.service
          1.109s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
          1.095s systemd-logind.service
           786ms dev-sda2.device
           770ms NetworkManager.service
           765ms snapd.service
           716ms fwupd.service
           668ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           644ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-296.mount
           640ms snap-core18-1066.mount
           557ms dev-loop1.device
           509ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-61.mount
           487ms dev-loop3.device
           456ms dev-loop4.device
           410ms mysql.service
           404ms snap-core-7270.mount
           367ms dev-loop5.device
           312ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1313.mount
           281ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-100.mount
           280ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-406.mount
           279ms snap-code-15.mount
           247ms dev-loop6.device
           227ms dev-loop0.device
           212ms dev-loop2.device
           178ms udisks2.service
           178ms apache2.service
           166ms ModemManager.service
           164ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           149ms networking.service
           140ms upower.service
           135ms dev-loop9.device
           135ms grub-common.service
           131ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-67.mount
           128ms apport.service
           123ms systemd-rfkill.service
           121ms avahi-daemon.service
           117ms networkd-dispatcher.service
           113ms alsa-restore.service
           113ms gpu-manager.service
           105ms rsyslog.service
           104ms pppd-dns.service
            93ms snap-htop-1168.mount
            83ms accounts-daemon.service
            81ms phpsessionclean.service
            71ms wpa_supplicant.service
            70ms swapfile.swap
            69ms thermald.service
            69ms speech-dispatcher.service
            65ms bluetooth.service
            64ms keyboard-setup.service
            55ms systemd-journald.service
            55ms systemd-udevd.service
            39ms user@1000.service
            37ms packagekit.service
            36ms systemd-resolved.service
            35ms user@121.service
            35ms systemd-timesyncd.service
            24ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
            21ms plymouth-start.service
            21ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-461C\x2d0619.service
            17ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
            17ms gdm.service
            13ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
            13ms snapd.seeded.service
            12ms polkit.service
            12ms colord.service
            11ms systemd-sysctl.service
             9ms dev-hugepages.mount
             9ms kmod-static-nodes.service
             9ms kerneloops.service
             9ms dev-loop8.device
             8ms dev-mqueue.mount
             7ms systemd-remount-fs.service
             7ms ureadahead-stop.service
             6ms dns-clean.service
             6ms boot-efi.mount
             5ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
             5ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             4ms systemd-update-utmp.service
             4ms systemd-random-seed.service
             3ms sys-kernel-config.mount
             3ms systemd-user-sessions.service
             3ms systemd-modules-load.service
             3ms console-setup.service
             3ms rtkit-daemon.service
             3ms nvidia-persistenced.service
             2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             2ms setvtrgb.service
             2ms snapd.socket
             2ms ufw.service
```

And the SATA version i typed this command 
`dmesg | grep -i sata | grep 'link up' | tail -n1`

The output is here :

```
[ 1923.391890] ata5: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
```

Comment: Can try ```systemd-analyze blame``` to see what is taking time, somethings can be delayed after you google for them.  Also do you know if your computer is using sata 3 or sata 2 for hard/ssd drive.

Comment: @crip659 I added the output of blame and SATA version.

Comment: If you google the first few one at a time you can see if they can be delayed till after.  The first one can be.  Can also decide if you want snaps or would be happy with the plain old fashion apps, to save time.  Snaps and snapd add to boot time.  You have sata 3 so that is good.