# How do i move my Linux boot and root partition to an SSD while retaining my home partition on the HDD

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I already have Linux installed on my 1TB HDD to separate partition the boot, root, and home are on a different partition.

My system partitioning scheme:

[image: My system partitioning scheme]

I got a 256GB SSD and I want to move the other partition to it except for the home partition. How do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 2):

- Boot from LiveCD (Ubuntu installation disk with **Try without installing**)
- Create the same partitions on SSD which you want to use using GParted except of `/home`.
- Create `/mnt/sddboot` and `/mnt/hddboot` folders
- Create `/mnt/sddopt` and `/mnt/hddopt` folders
- Create `/mnt/sddroot` and `/mnt/hddroot` folders
- Mount ssd partitions to your `/mnt/ssdXXX` mount points
- Mount hdd partitions to your `/mnt/hddXXX` mount points
- Copy everything from hdds to ssds saving ownership and timestamps: `rsync -avz --progress /mnt/hddXXX /mnt/ssdXXX`
- Edit `/etc/fstab` on SSD replacing UUIDs with `/dev/sd??` devices for `/`, `/home/`, `/boot`, `/opt` partitions. For example:

  ```
  /dev/sdTT /       xfs     defaults   0    0
  /dev/sdXX /boot   ext4    defaults   0    0
  /dev/sdYY /home   btrfs   defaults   0    0
  /dev/sdZZ /opt    btrfs   defaults   0    0
  ```
- Make your ssd bootable in GParted
- Install grub on your ssd: `grub-install /dev/sdX --skip-fs-probe --boot-directory=/mnt/ssdboot` where sdX is your ssd device. It could be `sda` or `sdb` or `sdc`. You could see it in GParted.
- Switch bootable disk to ssd in bios and verify by booting from it

Also, you could use [the next guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/842044/925971).

Comment: Not sure if anything is unique with XFS partitioning. But UUIDs in fstab will have to be updated with new UUIDs. And if separate /boot then that has to be in the mount  commands of installing grub.

Comment: Thanks i would try it today