# Removed grub by accident from via apt

Tags: boot, grub2

I removed grub fully via apt

```
 sudo apt purge grub-pc grub-common
```

I was going to reinstall via apt

```
 sudo apt install grub-pc grub-common
```

but my UPS failed and the PC shut-down. Now I am stuck. No grub nothing. Live cd shows no /boot/grub/grub.cfg

What to do?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Why your both commands are same in your question?

Comment: Thanx for pointing out. Edited

Comment: You should reinstall grub from livecd. For example this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/759291/how-to-reinstall-grub-by-ubuntu-14-04-live-cd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Backup
- Boot from live CD, DVD or USB drive
- Mount the partition your Ubuntu Installation is on. If you are not sure which it is, launch GParted (included in the Live CD) 
  or open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and use the following command:

  ```
  sudo fdisk -l
  ```

  and find out. It is usually a EXT4 Partition. Replacing the `XY` with the drive letter, and partition number, run these commands:

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
  sudo mount /dev/sdXZ /mnt  
  sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
  sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc 
  sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys 
  sudo chroot /mnt 
  sudo apt install grub-pc grub-common
  sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
  sudo update-grub
  exit
  sudo umount /mnt/dev 
  sudo umount /mnt/proc 
  sudo umount /mnt/sys 
  sudo umount /mnt
  ```
- Shut down and turn your computer back on, and you will be met with the default Grub2 screen.

Comment: Thanx [HRadl](https://askubuntu.com/users/884184/hradl)

Comment: [@Zanna](https://askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna) Do you need sudo after chroot?

Comment: It worked after I did `echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >/etc/resolv.conf` after `sudo chroot /mnt`